# How can I set just the year and month for date_select for HAML and Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, date, select, helper

I tried to set up the `date_select` in my HAML template for displaying just a year and month:

```
= date_select(:birthday, :order => [:day, :month, :year],:start_year => 1940)
```

I would expect this piece of code to display the select box sorted as: **day**, **month**, **year** and the year to start from 1940. This is not the case.

The select boxes are displayed as: CURRENT YEAR, CURRENT MONTH and CURRENT DAY.

How can I display just the select boxes for the year and month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select

`date_select(object_name, method, options = {}, html_options = {})`

There should be the method as second parameter and then the options.
Also I found on the documentation the option :discard_day, which doesn't display the select for the day.